# cakephp showing values instead of int

Tags: php, html, cakephp, enums

I have an int field in my cakephp project which translates into some values like here:

On my add

```
echo $form->input('bid_type', array('options' => array(
                '1'=>'CPC',
                '2'=>'CPM', )));
```

But when viewing this field i dont want the integers shown but the values.

How can i translate these values into strings when loaded?

Comment: What is the exact problem you facing..Sorry,But your language is bit confusing ...

Answer (score 2):

if you don't want integers just change the keys

```
echo $form->input('bid_type', array('options' => array(
                'CPC'=>'CPC',
                'CPM'=>'CPM', )));
```

this will give you CPC when selecting CPC etc... also the "values" are the keys of the array so technically it was giving you the values. The value of the array is just the display of the option, you may change it to whatever you need